# Calling controller function in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a callback on a controller from my custom directive. 
My aim to generate a search directive that can be re-used in multiple place. I want to pass it the function it needs to call on the attached controller via the function specified in the directive's attribute.

Plunkr URL is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/U7TA9NmdCgMxzZ8UBCvd?p=preview)

The code is as follows

```
<html ng-app="demo">

<head>
   <title>My Angular App</title>
   <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.1" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller='carsController'>
  <search-box placeholder="Search Cars" do-search="doSearch()"></search-box>
  <!--
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search Cars" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="doSearch()">search</button>    
  </form>
  -->
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="car in cars">
      <tr>
        <td>{{car.make}}</td>
        <td>{{car.model}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

---

```
app = angular.module('demo',[]);
//controllers
app.controller("carsController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.searchText = "";
$scope._cars = [
{
  'model': 'A4',
  'make':'Audi'
},
{
  'model':'328i',
  'make':'BMW'
}
];

$scope.cars = $scope._cars; 
$scope.doSearch = function() {
if($scope.searchText.length > 0) {
  $scope.cars = [];
  $scope._cars.forEach(function(car, index) {
  if(car.make.indexOf($scope.searchText) > -1) {
    $scope.cars.push(car);   
  }
}); 
} else {
  $scope.cars = $scope._cars;
}
}

$scope.resetSearch = function() {
  $scope.searchText = "";
  $scope.cars = $scope._cars;
}
}]);

// directives
app.directive("searchBox", searchBox);
function searchBox(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
       placeholder: '@',
       doSearch: '&'
    },
    link: searchBoxLink,
    templateUrl:'search.html'
  }
}

function searchBoxLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    scope.search = function() {
    scope.doSearch();
  }
}
```

---

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="search()">
      Search
    </button>
 </div>
</form>
```

I am a ng-noob and have read the documentation multiple times. Needless to say ng-directive still remains a mystery.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with your code. I fixed them in a [fork of your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/esStcpJDgZqT9LB4YUGw?p=preview).

#### Not binding the search text

You were relying on `$scope.searchText` to be the text the user entered in the filter's textbox, but didn't bind to that anywhere. Instead, in my version, I chose to make a `searchText` parameter available to the `do-search="doSearch(searchText)"` attribute expression. This means the `doSearch` function on the controller becomes:

```
$scope.doSearch = function(searchText) {
  // make sure its a string and lowercased
  searchText = (searchText || '').toString().toLocaleLowerCase();
  if (searchText.length > 0) {
    $scope.cars = [];
    $scope._cars.forEach(function(car, index) {
      if (car.make.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
        $scope.cars.push(car);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $scope.cars = $scope._cars;
  }
}
```

You will notice I also used [`.toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) (effectively the same as [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) but theoretically deals with unicode/funky characters better) to make sure I did a case insensitive search.

#### Other minor improvements

I added `ng-submit="search()"` to the form in the template for your directive so the user can press Enter to apply the filtering.

Comment: Thank you @GregL for the suggestions especially .toLocaleLowerCase( )

Comment: Related query. Can I call controllers method from 2 levels deep directive?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Could you please post a new question with as many details as you can include so I am clear what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code was not about the controller doSearch method. I could see the controller method is successfully invoked when the search button is clicked.

The issue was with the controller scope property `searchText`. Ideally, when you change the search text, this property should be set.

I modified your code a bit to pass the `searchText` to the directive and set to the search box input as ng-model.

see the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Izi5BbP39PxZbYkGeL2o?p=preview)